# Linear Layout add scrollView in programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

[image]

everything ok but I could not add Scrollview because I'm getting an error in scrollView.addView(mainlinearLayout);

There are similar questions but i didnt find the answer. I would be glad if you help me. Thanks

This is error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

This is activity_main.xml's Code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinLay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is MainActivity's Code

```
public void drawer() {
        String[] word=s.split(" ");
        scrollView=new ScrollView(this);
        mainlinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay);
        mainlinearLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        scrollView.addView(mainlinearLayout);
        childLinearLayout = getLinearLayout();


        for (int i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
            final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setTextSize(17);
            textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            textView.setText(word[i-1].toString());
            childLinearLayout.addView(textView);

            if (i % separatorNum == 0 && i != 0) {
                mainlinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                setContentView(mainlinearLayout);
                childLinearLayout=getLinearLayout();
            }

            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, and try to set `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` before calling this.

The problem is your LinearLayout already attached to activity view same Layout you are trying to add to `scrollview` so it was giving error.

```
public void drawer() {
    //String s = "sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd sdfsdf sdfs sdf sdf sdf sdfdsfsdf sfsdf ssdfdsf sdfsd";
    int separatorNum = 5;
    String[] word = s.split(" ");
    scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    mainlinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay);
    mainlinearLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    mainlinearLayout.addView(scrollView);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    LinearLayout childLinearLayout = getLinearLayout();


    for (int i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setTextSize(17);
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        textView.setText(word[i - 1].toString());
        childLinearLayout.addView(textView);

        if (i % separatorNum == 0 && i != 0) {
            linearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
           // setContentView(mainlinearLayout);
            childLinearLayout = getLinearLayout();
        }

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}

private LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
    LinearLayout childLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    childLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    childLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    return childLinearLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have activity_main.xml as your Activity's content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

then you are attaching your view to the activity, hence giving it (and the LinearLayout with id=LinLay) a parent.

If you want to make the ScrollView the main UI element in your Activity, then you should do

```
setContentView(scrollView)
```

or better yet do that in XML. Once the ScrollView is the parent, you can add your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a scroll view in layout.

if you are adding layout in scroll view then always remember you can add only one layout a scroll view. you can alternatively add linear layout in a scroll view and then can add number of layouts in the same.

Answer (score 0):

try below code it will check if child has parent or not,if there then remove the view,this will help you.

```
 public void drawer() {
                String[] word=s.split(" ");
                scrollView=new ScrollView(this);
                mainlinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay);
                mainlinearLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                scrollView.addView(mainlinearLayout);
                childLinearLayout = getLinearLayout();


                for (int i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
                    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textView.setTextSize(17);
                    textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    textView.setText(word[i-1].toString());
    if (textView.getParent() != null) {
                            ((ViewGroup) textView.getParent()).removeView(textView);
                        }
                    childLinearLayout.addView(textView);

                    if (i % separatorNum == 0 && i != 0) {
                        mainlinearLayout.addView(childLinearLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                        setContentView(mainlinearLayout);
                        childLinearLayout=getLinearLayout();
                    }

                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your trying to add exiting layout to scroll-view its giving error, so try to add scroll-view to your existing layout

don't know it will serve your requirement or not .

Try this method

```
public void drawer() {
        String[] word=s.split(" ");
        ScrollView  scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        mainlinearLayout_ = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay);
        mainlinearLayout_.removeAllViews();
        scrollView.removeAllViews();
        mainlinearLayout_.addView(scrollView);
        LinearLayout  verticalLinearLayout = new  LinearLayout(this);
        verticalLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            LinearLayout horizontalChildLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            horizontalChildLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
                final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                textView.setTextSize(17);
                textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                textView.setText(word[i - 1].toString());


                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                horizontalChildLinearLayout.addView(textView);
            }
            verticalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalChildLinearLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
        scrollView.addView(verticalLinearLayout);
    }
```

Thank you.